# Harddrive not connecting after login

Tags: macos

I have an external monitor with USB ports which is connected via mini DVI cable to my laptop and additionally via usb for the hub. An external hard drive is connected to this monitor.
Normally, when I connect my mac to the monitor, I first connect the mini DVI cable so the monitor switches on, as well as the USB hub within the monitor. Then I connect my USB cable. 
My problem is, the Harddrive is not recognised by the system. I have to unplug and replug the disk so it gets mounted.

Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Are you logged in when you connect your monitor and hub? In my experience, external drives don't get mounted when connecting them before logging in.

Comment: Thats true, my laptop is closed and I connect the cables. There is also a keyboard on the hub so I log in afterwards... Is there a way to trigger the mounting without disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an [old question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/360276/automount-external-hard-drive-on-mac) that may help:

> I found a preference that might do the trick:
>
> ```
> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount
> ```
>
> AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin true

Please report if it helps

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. The drive is still not connecting automatically...